# How to proceed in my case to display text over the image in CSS?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have the following CSS sheet for a responsive flip card that is displaying two background images on both sides. I am trying to get text on top of them, but it is not showing in the browser for some reason. Here is the CSS:

```
.container {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0px auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
}

.card {
  width: 90%;
  border-radius:20px;
  height: 170px;
  margin: 10 auto;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.face:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  height: 22px;
  width: 100%;
  background: url('http://media.a-g.fr/crea/talenance/shadow.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.face {
  border-radius:20px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
  color: white;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
}

.front {
  background: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/eomerx/128.jpg) center center;
  background-size:cover;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4em;
  position: absolute;
}

.back {
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #28255f;
  transform:rotateY(180deg);
}

.back a {
  line-height: 250px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
}

.back a:before {
  content:"";
  background-size:cover;
  position: absolute;
  width:50px;
  height: 50px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:0 auto;
  filter:invert(100%) brightness(150%);
  -webkit-filter:invert(100%) brightness(150%);
}

.back a:nth-of-type(1):before {
  background:url(http://media.a-g.fr/crea/talenance/linkedin.png) no-repeat center center;
  top:30px;
}

.back a:nth-of-type(2):before {
  background:url(http://media.a-g.fr/crea/talenance/email.png) no-repeat center center;
  bottom:30px;
}

.back a:hover {
  opacity:0.5;
}

.card:hover .front {
  transform:rotateY(-180deg);
}

.card:hover .back {
  transform:rotateY(0deg);
}
```

I am trying to insert text there on top of the background image, but I am not sure why this HTML doesn't work:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 cardContainer">
        <div class="card" id="card"> 
            <div class="face front">

                TEXT HERE

            </div>
            <div class="face back">
                <a href="#"></a>
                <a href="#"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank for your help!

Comment: Do you want to move the text to top of front face?

Comment: Remove line-height from the face class css :)

Comment: It is not working by removing the line-height from the face class css. No text in browser. Just image.

Comment: I want to show the text and format it.

Answer (score 1):

Add `line-height:1;` to class front or remove `line-height: 300px;` from class face, depending on your use for class face elsewhere.

```css
.container {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0px auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;


}

.card {


width: 90%;
  border-radius:20px;
  height: 170px;
  margin: 10 auto;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;

}
.face:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  height: 22px;
  width: 100%;
  background: url('http://media.a-g.fr/crea/talenance/shadow.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
.face {
  border-radius:20px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
  color: white;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
      transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;

}



.front {


  background: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/eomerx/128.jpg) center center;
  background-size:cover;
  z-index: 2;



text-align: center;
  font-size: 4em;
  position: absolute;
line-height:1;

}


.back {
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #28255f;
  transform:rotateY(180deg);
}

.back a {
    line-height: 250px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
}

.back a:before {
  content:"";
  background-size:cover;
  position: absolute;
  width:50px;
  height: 50px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:0 auto;
    filter:invert(100%) brightness(150%);
  -webkit-filter:invert(100%) brightness(150%);
}

.back a:nth-of-type(1):before {
 background:url(http://media.a-g.fr/crea/talenance/linkedin.png) no-repeat center center;
    top:30px;
}
.back a:nth-of-type(2):before {
 background:url(http://media.a-g.fr/crea/talenance/email.png) no-repeat center center;
    bottom:30px;
}



.back a:hover {
  opacity:0.5;
}

.card:hover .front{
  transform:rotateY(-180deg);
}
.card:hover .back{
  transform:rotateY(0deg);
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 cardContainer">
<div class="card" id="card"> 
    <div class="face front">

TEXT HERE

</div>
    <div class="face back">
      <a href="#"></a>
      <a href="#"></a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `line-height` from `.face` selector.

Final css:

```
.container {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0px auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;


}

.card {


width: 90%;
  border-radius:20px;
  height: 170px;
  margin: 10 auto;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;

}
.face:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  height: 22px;
  width: 100%;
  background: url('http://media.a-g.fr/crea/talenance/shadow.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
.face {
  border-radius:20px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  /*line-height: 300px;*/
  color: white;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
      transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;

}



.front {


  background: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/eomerx/128.jpg) center center;
  background-size:cover;
  z-index: 2;



text-align: center;
  font-size: 4em;
  position: absolute;


}


.back {
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #28255f;
  transform:rotateY(180deg);
}

.back a {
    line-height: 250px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
}

.back a:before {
  content:"";
  background-size:cover;
  position: absolute;
  width:50px;
  height: 50px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:0 auto;
    filter:invert(100%) brightness(150%);
  -webkit-filter:invert(100%) brightness(150%);
}

.back a:nth-of-type(1):before {
 background:url(http://media.a-g.fr/crea/talenance/linkedin.png) no-repeat center center;
    top:30px;
}
.back a:nth-of-type(2):before {
 background:url(http://media.a-g.fr/crea/talenance/email.png) no-repeat center center;
    bottom:30px;
}



.back a:hover {
  opacity:0.5;
}

.card:hover .front{
  transform:rotateY(-180deg);
}
.card:hover .back{
  transform:rotateY(0deg);
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/v5g9eg1e/

Comment: Thanks but it is not working for some reason. Text still is probably under the image...

Answer (score 0):

CSS I hope this is what you are looking For.

```
.container {
padding: 1em;
margin: auto;
max-width: 100%;
text-align: center;
-webkit-perspective: 800px;
perspective: 800px;
}

.card {
width: 90%;
border-radius:20px;
height: 170px;
margin: 10 auto;
position: relative;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.face:after {
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 0;
z-index: -1;
display: block;
content: '';
height: 22px;
width: 100%;
background: url('http://media.a-g.fr/crea/talenance/shadow.png') no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
}

.face {
border-radius:20px;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
text-align: center;
line-height: 300px;
color: white;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
}   

.front {
background: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/eomerx/128.jpg) center center;
background-size:cover;
z-index: 2;
text-align: center;
font-size: 4em;
position: absolute;
}

.back {
z-index: 1;
background-color: #28255f;
transform:rotateY(180deg);
}

.back a {
line-height: 250px;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 700;
text-decoration: none;
width: 100%;
height: 50%;
text-align: center;
color: black;
display: block;
transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
}

.back a:before {
 content:"";
 background-size:cover;
 position: absolute;
 width:50px;
 height: 50px;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 margin:0 auto;
 filter:invert(100%) brightness(150%);
-webkit-filter:invert(100%) brightness(150%);
}

.back a:nth-of-type(1):before {
 background:url(http://media.a-g.fr/crea/talenance/linkedin.png) no-repeat center center;
 top:30px;
}

.back a:nth-of-type(2):before {
background:url(http://media.a-g.fr/crea/talenance/email.png) no-repeat center center;
bottom:30px;
}

.back a:hover {
opacity:0.5;
}

.card:hover .front {
transform:rotateY(-180deg);
}

.card:hover .back {
transform:rotateY(0deg);
}

 #text {
  text-align: center}
```

HTML

```
<div id="text">
<h2>TEXT HERE<h2>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 cardContainer">
    <div class="card" id="card"> 
        <div class="face front">
        </div>
        <div class="face back">
            <a href="#"></a>
            <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is clearly not where I want the text to appear.

Comment: ok then how do you want it to appear or is the line height adjustment working for u?